# How to catch the return value in json from a webmethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery

Net and Webmethods for using JSON

My webmethod Return value is given as

```
    return ResultValue;
      // which gives 1 as Return Value on SUcessfull insertion
```

If the return value is 1 I want it to show in my JQuery as success

for that how should I catch the return value which is in my webmethod??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {  

      //data=ResultValue

      if(data == 1)
       { // Success Stuff }else {//do stuff}

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mypage.html',
  success: function(data){
    if(data ==1)
       alert('success');
    else
       alert('failure');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or you set the status code for your Response object in your webmethod. Something like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = 500; // or whatever code is appropriate
Response.End;
```